# Count(*) in SQL spanning multiple columns

Tags: sql, count, multiple-columns

I have a table similar to this

[image]

Can I get help writing up a query which will join col1, col2 & col3 and give me a result as below

[image]

I've spent an hour trying to figure it out with my mediocre skills and have got to some point.

```
select col1, count(*) 
from tableName 
group by col1
```

But I can't figure out how to join all three cols.

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
select
    col,
    count(*)
from
    (select
         id,
         col1 as col
     from
         <table_name>
     union all
     select
         id,
         col2
     from
         <table_name>
     union all
     select
         id,
         col3
     from
         <table_name>)
group by
    col
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to group by col of the union of the 3 columns:

```
select t.col, count(*)
from (
  select col1 col from tablename
  union all
  select col2 from tablename
  union all
  select col3 from tablename
) t
group by t.col
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [UNION](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_ref_union.asp) to group values from all columns to one column. After that, you can count values

```
SELECT 
   col,
   count(*) as cnt
FROM
  (SELECT col1 as col FROM table1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT col2 as col FROM table1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT col2 as col FROM table1) as t
GROUP BY col
```

Comment: This one worked like a charm. Thanks all for such lightening fast responses.